# I cannot pass the value from the file to the struct

Tags: c, file, pointers, struct

I'm a beginner in C, I'm trying to read a file in order to update a struct but every time I do it it gives me an error (I'm working with visual studio 2013).

This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Registro{
    int cedula;
    char nombre[20];
    char apellido[20];
    char direccion[50];
    int ingreso;
};


void agregarP(struct Registro * informacion, int * n){
    int op,i,aux;
    printf("Cuantas personas desea agregar?\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf_s("%i", &op);
    aux = op;
    op += *n;
    for (i = *n; i < op; i++){
        printf("Introduzca la cedula\n");
        scanf_s("%i", &informacion[i].cedula);
        printf("Introduzca el nombre\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets_s(informacion[i].nombre);
        printf("Introduzca el apellido\n");
        gets_s(informacion[i].apellido);
        printf("Introduzca la direccion\n");
        gets_s(informacion[i].direccion);
        printf("Introduzca el ingrso anual\n");
        scanf_s("%i", &informacion[i].ingreso);
        system("cls");
    }
    *n += aux;
}

bool comprobacion(int n1, int n2){
    if (n1 == n2){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

void borrar(struct Registro * s, int *n){
    int i, ced;
    struct Registro aux;
    bool compr;
    printf("Introduzca la cedula de la persona que desea borrar\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf_s("%i",&ced);
    for (i = 0; i < *n; i++){
        if (s[i].cedula == ced){
            compr = comprobacion(*n, i);
            if (compr){
                break;
            }
            else{
                aux = s[*n - 1];
                s[*n - 1] = s[i];
                s[i] = aux;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    *n -= 1;
}

void mostrar(struct Registro * informacion, int n){
    int i;
    printf("Cedula \t     Nombre \t     Apellido \t Direccion \t  Ingreso \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%i \t ", informacion[i].cedula);
        printf("%s \t ", informacion[i].nombre);
        printf("%s \t ", informacion[i].apellido);
        printf("%s \t ", informacion[i].direccion);
        printf("%i \n", informacion[i].ingreso);
    }
}


void mostrarPorOrden(struct Registro * s, int n){
    int i, j,cont = 0, op;
    struct Registro aux;
    printf("1 para mostrar por orden de cedula\n");
    printf("2 para mostrar por orden de apellido\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf_s("%i", &op);
    switch (op){
    case 1: for (i = 0; i < n+1; i++){
                cont = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (s[j].cedula > s[j + 1].cedula){
                        aux = s[j+1];
                        s[j + 1] = s[j];
                        s[j] = aux;
                        cont++;
                    }
                }
                if (cont == 0) break;
    }
            mostrar(s, n);
            break;
    case 2: for (i = 0; i < n + 1; i++){
                cont = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (s[j].apellido[0] > s[j + 1].apellido[0]){
                        aux = s[j+1];
                        s[j + 1] = s[j];
                        s[j] = aux;
                        cont++;
                    }
                }
                if (cont == 0) break;
    }
            mostrar(&s[0], n);
            break;
    }
}

void guardarArch(FILE * ff, struct Registro * s, int n){
    fopen_s(&ff, "Datos.txt", "w");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        fprintf(ff,"%d", s[i].cedula); fprintf(ff, "\n");
        fprintf(ff, s[i].nombre); fprintf(ff, "\n");
        fprintf(ff, s[i].apellido); fprintf(ff, "\n");
        fprintf(ff, s[i].direccion); fprintf(ff, "\n");
        fprintf(ff, "%d",s[i].ingreso); fprintf(ff, "\n");

    }

        fclose(ff);
}

void leerArch(FILE * ff, struct Registro * s, int * n){
    fopen_s(&ff, "Datos.txt", "r");
    int i = 0;
    while (!feof(ff)){

    }
    fclose(ff);
}

void main(){
    FILE * infor = new FILE;
    struct Registro informacion[30];
    int op = -1;
    int persona = 0;
    while (op != 0){
        printf("1 para agregar una persona\n");
        printf("2 para mostrar\n");
        printf("3 para borrar\n");
        printf("4 para mostrar ordenado\n");
        printf("5 para guardarlo en un archivo\n");
        printf("6 para leer de un archivo\n");
        printf("0 para salir\n");
        scanf_s("%i", &op);
        fflush(stdin);
        switch (op)
        {
        case 1: agregarP(&informacion[0], &persona);
            printf("%i", persona);
            break;
        case 2: mostrar(&informacion[0], persona);
            break;
        case 3: borrar(&informacion[0], &persona);
            break;
        case 4: mostrarPorOrden(&informacion[0], persona);
            break;
        case 5: guardarArch(infor, &informacion[0], persona);
            break;
        case 6: leerArch(infor, &informacion[0], &persona);
            break;
        }
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
    }
}
```

PD: Sorry for my english.

Edited.

This is the part where I'm having trouble, it breaks automatically. It reads the stuff now but with a lot of new lines

```
int ayudaLeer(FILE * ff, struct Registro * s, int * n){
    if (feof(ff)) return -1;
    char * c = new char[];
    int p = fgetc(ff);
    fscanf_s(ff, "%d", &s[*n].cedula);
    fgets(c, 20, ff);
    fgets(s[*n].nombre, 20, ff);
    fgets(s[*n].apellido, 20, ff);
    fgets(s[*n].direccion, 20, ff);
    fscanf_s(ff, "%d", &s[*n].ingreso);
    *n+=1;
    ayudaLeer(ff, s, n);
}

void leerArch(FILE * ff, struct Registro * s, int * n){
    fopen_s(&ff, "Datos.txt", "r");
    int i = 0;
    ayudaLeer(ff, s, &i);
    *n = i-1;
    fclose(ff);
}
```

Comment: You should include the error you get

Comment: Can you give us the exact error and how are you compiling?

Comment: In C, `gets_s(informacion[i].nombre);`  --> that needs 2 arguments,  size missing.  What did the compiler say about this line?  Are warnings all enabled?

Comment: So your whole program is a single error? Hardly. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` -> undefined behaviour.

Comment: You don't show us where/what/how your read from the file. Can't help you then, however, if you do all those `fprintfs`, what makes you think you can read a `struct`? What about `fscanf`?